# How can I reset position when I call resetStack method?

Tags: android

while working with SwipeStack, how can I manage position?

```
case R.id.fab:
     mSwipeStack.resetStack();
     if (mData != null)
         cardProgress.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.default_text) + mData.size());
      break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make lastSwipedPosition to zero and reset your stack.

```
            case R.id.fab:
            lastSwipedPosition = 0;
            mSwipeStack.resetStack();
            break;
```

> Edited

```
        swipedLastPosition =0;
        mTempData.clear();
        mTempData.addAll(mData);
        mSwipeStack.resetStack();
```

Comment: Ok let me check.please wait.

Comment: waiting dude, obviously

Comment: same here and waiting for more questions to ask:)

Comment: Morning, Navneet!

Comment: A question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987945/how-can-i-manage-count-of-swiped-cards

Comment: yr, actually while swiping cards, I also set Textview like 2 Out of 8...but when I click previous button and then swipe again, that time it is not showing properly.

Comment: Also I found a bug in our code. Everything is alright, but while swiping if I press next button and then previous that time order is not maintaining.