# How can I manage count of swiped cards?

Tags: android

I'm implementing Swipe stack demo from [here.](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack) Now I want track progress of swiped cards. I already made my own logic, and it's working pretty fine. but I've one more functionality, which is while clicking on previous button, user can see one by one all swiped cards in reverse order.

But my swiped card progress stack is not working in that case. How can I do this?

Explain: not total swiped cards count, but which one card is currently I'm seeing like 4 Out of 10

DisplayCardActivity:

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.Adapter.SwipeStackAdapter;
import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.Data.FetchDataFromUriAsyncTask;
import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.Listener.JSONDataListener;
import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.R;
import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.View.SwipeStack;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class DisplayCardActivity extends BaseActivity implements SwipeStack.SwipeStackListener, View.OnClickListener, JSONDataListener {
    public static final String TAG = DisplayCardActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.previous)
    ImageButton mPrevious;
    @BindView(R.id.next)
    ImageButton mNext;
    @BindView(R.id.swipe_stack)
    SwipeStack mSwipeStack;
    @BindView(R.id.fab)
    FloatingActionButton mFAB;
    @BindView(R.id.card_progress)
    TextView cardProgress;

    private FetchDataFromUriAsyncTask dataFromUriAsyncTask;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private ArrayList<String> mTempData;
    private int mCurrentCardPosition = 1, lastSwipedPosition = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_display_card;
    }

    private void init() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setClickListener();
        mTempData = new ArrayList<>();
        mPrevious.setEnabled(false);
        mPrevious.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
        dataFromUriAsyncTask = new FetchDataFromUriAsyncTask(this, this);
        dataFromUriAsyncTask.setJSONDataListener(this);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loadDataFromUrl();
    }

    private void setClickListener() {
        mPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
        mNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFAB.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void loadDataFromUrl() {
        //Showing progress dialog
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data from...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        dataFromUriAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    private void changePreviousButtonStatus(int positionValue) {
        if (lastSwipedPosition == positionValue) {
            mPrevious.setEnabled(false);
            mPrevious.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
        } else {
            mPrevious.setEnabled(true);
            mPrevious.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.previous:
                changePreviousButtonStatus(1);
                lastSwipedPosition = lastSwipedPosition - 1;
                if (lastSwipedPosition >= 0) {
                    mTempData.clear();
                    for (int i = lastSwipedPosition; i < mData.size(); i++) {
                        mTempData.add(mData.get(i));
                    }
                    mSwipeStack.resetStack();
                    setCurrentCardPosition(lastSwipedPosition);
                } else {
                    lastSwipedPosition = 0;
                }

                break;

            case R.id.next:
                changePreviousButtonStatus(1);
                mSwipeStack.swipeTopViewToRight();
                break;

            case R.id.fab:
                mPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                mPrevious.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                lastSwipedPosition = 0;
                mTempData.clear();
                mTempData.addAll(mData);
                mSwipeStack.resetStack();
                if (mData != null)
                    cardProgress.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.default_count) + mData.size());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
        mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;
        setCurrentCardPosition(mCurrentCardPosition);
        lastSwipedPosition = position + 1;
        changePreviousButtonStatus(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
        mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;
        setCurrentCardPosition(mCurrentCardPosition);
        lastSwipedPosition = position + 1;
        changePreviousButtonStatus(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStackEmpty() {
        cardProgress.setText("No card in stack");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClickData(ArrayList<String> getData) {
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();


        mData = new ArrayList<>(getData);
        mTempData.addAll(mData);
        setCurrentCardPosition(mCurrentCardPosition);
        SwipeStackAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeStackAdapter(mTempData);

        mSwipeStack.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mSwipeStack.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onJSONParsingError(String error) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        showToast(getString(R.string.user_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    private void showToast(String message, int length) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, length).show();
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }

    private void setCurrentCardPosition(int currentPosition) {
        cardProgress.setText(currentPosition + " Out of " + mData.size());
    }


}
```

Adapter:

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.Adapter;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jimmytrivedi.cardswipedemo.R;

import java.util.List;

public class SwipeStackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final String TAG = SwipeStackAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<String> mData;

    public SwipeStackAdapter(List<String> data) {
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        TextView textViewCard = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard);
        textViewCard.setText(mData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

Use case: I've 10 cards (001, 002..010). And there are total 5 things. 
1. Left swipe
2. Right seipe
3. Previous button
4. Next button
5. Reset button

If I start right swiping 001 then 002 now I pressed next button for 003 and 004. Now I pressed previous button then again next and again previous,. That time order is not mainting.

Comment: why dont you add the swiped cards in another temporary array then add the element to the swipe cards original list one by one upon clicking. this could work.

Comment: @SanketPatel That's what exactly I did. Kindly check there mData and mTempData

Comment: `mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;` Why increment by 2?

Comment: @sanjeev Cause my app: stack size and getchilderncount is 3

Comment: use Observer Pattern to manage position which is help you to click your next and previous button.Then get new position shown in card which you have orginal arraylist .

Comment: Hi Deepali
Can you please post your adaptor class?

Comment: @NavneetSharma posted

Comment: @NavneetSharma Actually you know there are one more problem. there is next button also, so if I press next button and then previous that time also card positioning showing random

Answer (score 0):

Hold a global variable and increment it on `SwipeLeft` and `SwipeRight` callback

```
private int totalCardsSwiped = 0;

@Override
public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
totalCardsSwiped++; }

@Override
public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
totalCardsSwiped++; }
```

Comment: not total swiped cards, which card is currently I'm seeing like 4 Out of 10

Comment: @DipaliSingh I'm not able to understand correctly,Do you mean the current position of the card being swiped?

Comment: suppose I've 10 cards. first card name is "1", secind is "2"...and so on till "10". Now I want to know that which card is displayed currently. like if second card is visible it means 2 out of 10

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in swiped callback methods?

**mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;**

I think here is the problem.

or you can call this  **setCurrentCardPosition()** method with the current position

```
@Override
public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
    mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;
    setCurrentCardPosition(position);
    lastSwipedPosition = position + 1;
    changePreviousButtonStatus(0);
}

@Override
public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
    mCurrentCardPosition = position + 2;
    setCurrentCardPosition(position);
    lastSwipedPosition = position + 1;
    changePreviousButtonStatus(0);
}
```

> Edited

int currentPosition = 1;

After Adding Data in list

```
txtCardProgress.setText("1 out of " + mData.size());
```

in onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(mButtonLeft)) {
        swipedLastPosition = swipedLastPosition - 1;
        currentPosition =currentPosition -1;
        if (swipedLastPosition >= 0) {
            mTempData.clear();//clear all data
            for (int i = swipedLastPosition; i < mData.size(); i++) {
                mTempData.add(mData.get(i));
            }
            mSwipeStack.resetStack();
            if (swipedLastPosition == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "hide back button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            currentPosition =currentPosition -1;
            setCardProgress(currentPosition);
        } else {
            swipedLastPosition = 0;
            currentPosition = 0;
            setCardProgress(currentPosition);
        }

    } else if (v.equals(mButtonRight)) {
        mSwipeStack.swipeTopViewToRight();
    } else if (v.equals(mFab)) {
        swipedLastPosition = 0;
        mTempData.clear();
        mTempData.addAll(mData);
        mSwipeStack.resetStack();
        setCardProgress(swipedLastPosition);
    }
```

Callback Methods

```
@Override
public void onViewSwipedToRight(int position) {
    swipedLastPosition = position + 1;
    setCardProgress(position);
}

@Override
public void onViewSwipedToLeft(int position) {
    swipedLastPosition = position;     
    setCardProgress(position);
}
```

Update Progress method

```
void setCardProgress(int position) {
    if (position == mData.size()-1) {
        currentPosition = mData.size();
        txtCardProgress.setText(currentPosition + " out of " + mData.size());
    } else {
        currentPosition++;
        txtCardProgress.setText(currentPosition + " out of " + mData.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, it's not working. for second card position is showing 0.

Comment: do one thing, copy my class from above code and run into your project, so that you'll get updated code.

Comment: Actually, I was busy. yes I tried, but it's not working properly. And the problem is next button. As I previously told you that Everything is alright, but while swiping if I press next button and then previous then next then previous that time order is not maintaining.

Comment: Are you there dear? or still party?

Comment: Hahaha, no party.
I was busy in my work

dipali i think you might need to change your library.
because the work you want to achieve is already done in some other libraries.

consider this: https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

Comment: Are yar, again new library and all? can't you find some way in our current project?

Comment: umm.. and again I've to copy those all classes in my project and change the flow :(

Comment: dear its outdated project .
you should not use this but like you are facing minor problems its already handled in other available sdk's.

Comment: and if we solve this you might be again fall in some other issues.

Comment: Lol .. acha let's see what can we do.

Comment: Hi can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234945/how-to-fix-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-of

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: hi.
will check in sometime

Comment: ohhh ..Good.
let me know if you have more bugs :P